# Parsing "Bytes (Offset Hex text)"

Tags: php, regex, hex

You can copy bytes data from udp packet using wireshark.
[image: wireshark]

And it produces data like this

```
00f00:   21 00 d2 0c 17 ca d9 2f fe 40 be 01 00 37 fa 83  !....../.@...7..
00f09:   21 00 d2 0c 17 ca d9 2f fe 40 be 01 00 37 fa 83  !....../.@...7..
00f10:   2c b3 bd a2                                      ,...
```

how can i get all bytes in array (`21 00 d2 0c 17 ca d9 2f fe 40 be 01 00 37 fa 83 2c b3 bd a2`) from this text table, using **php regex**? (from every line into single php array of bytes, or even better into **string**)

i need to parse not only wireshark data (so suggestion about Bytes(Offset Hex) is not working)

Comment: A line contains 16 bytes exact, right? Using `strpos` and `substr` seems to be a much simpler way if it's that

Comment: Why don't you just use the `Copy` -> `Bytes (Hex Stream)` option?

Comment: from example you can see, it's not always 16 bytes, it can be from 1 to 16 bytes. And "Bytes (Hex Stream)" not working because i need to parse similar table from other program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple solution would be to combine string manipulation with a simple regex, like so:

```
$output = '';
foreach( explode( "\n", $input) as $line) {
    if( preg_match( '/(?:[a-f0-9]{2}\s){1,16}/i', $line, $matches)) {
        $output .= ' ' . $matches[0];
    }
}

$output = trim( $output);
var_dump( $output);
```

This [outputs](http://viper-7.com/ltGccb):

```
string(109) "21 00 d2 0c 17 ca d9 2f fe 40 be 01 00 37 fa 83 21 00 d2 0c 17 ca d9 2f fe 40 be 01 00 37 fa 83 2c b3 bd a2"
```

Comment: sorry, but this take only first byte from every line

Comment: @Fedcomp - Not according to my demo, which takes your input exactly and uses it to parse the hex bytes. You'll have to update your question to an input case that's failing in order for me to fix it.